# How to disable "exclusion" in `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have this in my `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration
      - ..... <other exclusions>
```

Then, in `application-redis.yml` profile I want to re-enable this auto-configuration.

What I could do apart from copying the whole list without just one entry?

Please don't suggest the solutions based on code modification (like specific annotations etc. - I need to do it with properties only). Also, I cannot make this auto-configuration enabled initially and add some kind of the "default" profile where it's disabled.

Answer (score 2):

#### Profile/Import approach

1. Create a (custom, auto-scanned, possibly empty) `@Configuration`.
2. Annotate it with `@Profile("redis")`.
3. Annotate it additionally with `@Import(RedisAutoConfiguration.class)`.

Done! Looks like:

```java
package com.my.package;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration;

@Configuration
@Profile("redis")
@Import(RedisAutoConfiguration.class)
// config more here...
class MyRedisConfig {
  // ..or here
}
```

...this *will* re-import the `application.yaml`-excludes (for RedicAutoConfig class only), *when activating "redis" profile*.

Not sure whether this is "quicker", than the copy&paste approach, but sounds exactly what, configuration+import+profile were "designed for"!;)

> If a `@Configuration` class is marked with `@Profile`, all of the `@Bean` methods and ***`@Import`*** annotations associated with that class will be bypassed unless one or more of the specified profiles are active

- [Spring Boot Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles)
- [Configuration javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)
- [Import javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html)
- [Profile javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)